# Having difficulty installing recaptcha

Tags: recaptcha

I am trying to install recaptcha using recaptcha--client. I tried typing `easy_install recaptcha-client`

Having this error:

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/easy_install-2.7", line 10, in <module>
    load_entry_point('setuptools==0.6c12dev-r85381', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 318, in load_entry_point
    """Locate distribution `dist_spec` and run its `script_name` script"""
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2220, in load_entry_point
```

Not sure how to solve this error...

Answer (score 0):

download recaptcha-client from this website: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/recaptcha-client and cd into the path and type `python setup.py install`